# Install make 3.75 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-15.10

I am new to ubuntu. I am looking for any help in installing GNU Make version 3.75 or other older version on ubuntu 15.10. I understand that the package for older version doesnot exist for ubuntu 15.10 and I am not able to get the instruction anywhere on how to get the packages. 
Any help regarding this is appreciated.TIA

Comment: why do you need that specific version? Just fix your makefile that it works with later versions

Comment: Pls see my comment to @reinierpost 's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep make
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.75.tar.gz
tar xvf make-3.75.tar.gz
cd make-3.75
./configure
make
sudo make install prefix=/opt/make-3.75
# or sudo make install to install it into /usr/local
```

Why do you need this? As arved suggests: if your Makefiles are 20 years old and incompatible with current versions of `make`, and can't be fixed, you probably have bigger problems elsewhere. Whatever those Makefiles try to do may require some tweaking to work on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: I am trying to build android source (gingerbread version) and keep getting the Make error `build/core/prebuilt.mk:123: *** recipe commences before first target. Stop.` I have checked for tabs and spaces and everything seems to be as it should. It was suggested in a forum to use version 3.8 of Make to solve this ([here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/90426-help-i-need-help-building-cm72/)). I am not particular about 3.75 but wanted to switch to older version.

Comment: I don't think an older version would help. I would check the line endings on the file (Windows, Unix and Mac have different ways of ending lines) and whether there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or some potential other source of confusion at the start.